# c# - how to catch errors/warnings while adding data to a custom list in sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013 Custom Lists you can define whether a field can be empty or not, or min-max value for numbers e.t.c. While using Sharepoint's own form to add data to custom lists, it warns you.

I also add data to that list through a webpart. Code sample is below, it adds my data but never gives error. It creates record even values are empty.

I tried try-catch but didn't help. how can I catch these warnings, what I'm mising here?

```
try
{
    SPList mylist = web.Lists.TryGetList("mylist");
    SPListItem item = mylist.Items.Add();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    item.Update();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Literal2.Text = "An error occurred: '" + err + "'";
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation which you put at time of creating columns are just validation for SharePoint GUI. It will not validate at C# level.